# MYSQL Database Copy Using Python/Django

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, database

I need to create a copy of the database in my MySQL Server using Django Application

After a little research, i found mysqldump as the better approach

```py
backup_file_path = f"/tmp/{src_database_name}_backup.sql"

backup_db_command = f"mysqldump -h {SQL_DB_HOST} -P 3306 -u {SQL_DB_USER} -p{SQL_DB_PASSWORD} {src_database_name} > {backup_file_path}"

print(backup_db_command)  # TODO: remove

with os.popen(backup_db_command, "r") as p:
    r = p.read()
    print(f"Backup Output: {r}")

restore_command = f"mysql -u root -p{SQL_DB_PASSWORD} {dest_database_name} < {backup_file_path}"

with os.popen(restore_command, "r") as p:
    r = p.read()
    print(f"Restore Output: {r}")
```

**My Queries:**

1. Any issues with this approach
2. Any better approaches to do a copy of DB using Either python or Django ORM

Comment: Its not terrible. Why do it in Django however. You could pipe `mysqldump | mysql` rather than a temporary file. If its only going to be a small database then this is probably quite adequate. I'd use `--single-transaction` on the dump to minimize application impacts and to create a consistent snapshot. Also do you have routines/functions? If so add them to the mysqldump.

Comment: I've do this copies for Large Databases frequently, and there are 10's of such databases, so we're using Django to manage those copies @danblack

Comment: For frequent copies consider > 20G as large (unless very limited hardware). Beyond that consider taking the `mysqldump` from a replica (but still pipe over network to new instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Using django-admin, Django’s command-line utility for dumpdata and loaddata.

**Use the following command to dump data**

- django-admin dumpdata [app_label[.ModelName] [app_label[.ModelName]
  ...]] -o  database_backup.sql

**Use the following command to load data**

- django-admin loaddata database_backup.sql

docs-
[dump data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata)
[load data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/#loaddata)

Comment: I need a Copy database util for a specified database, not just for database configured in Django settings